# Remove duplicate lines from file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, sublimetext3

I have a list of URLs, most of which are duplicates:

```
> http://example.com/some/a-test-link.html
> http://example.com/some/a-test-link.html
> http://example.com/some/another-link.html
> http://example.com/some/another-link.html
> http://example.com/some/again-link.html
> http://example.com/some/again-link.html
```

I don't need the same link twice, so I need to remove duplicates and keep only one link. How can I do this using regular expressions, or `sed`, or `awk` (I am not sure which technology would be best). I am using Ubuntu as the operating system and Sublime Text 3 as my editor.

Comment: It might be easier to just use uniq to filter duplicates: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq

Comment: hello @ChrisLaplante , Yes it works using `uniq -d filename.txt newname.txt`. Thank you very much!  

But how can we do this using regex? just curiosity.

Comment: unix tools work with one line of data at a time. `uniq -d` is a special case, in that it keeps the previous line for comparison. `sed` could use a regex to compare one line with the previous, but its really not what `sed` is designed to do, if you're not an expert. `awk` would keep a copy of the previous line, just like `uniq -d`, but you would only be using the string comparison operator `==`, and not a regex. If you want to get good at this, read the O'Reilly `sed and awk` book. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, thanks for your valuable comments, I am actually a newbie and learning by doing!

Comment: Do not get that `sed and awk` book. You don't need a book at all to learn what sed is good for (simple substitutions on a single line) and the book `Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition` by Robins is more comprehensive and more current for learning awk. You should also consider the book `Shell Scripting Recipes` by Johnson.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thanks for your recommendation! I appreciated

Comment: Since `sublimetext3` is specifically tagged and the edits floated this to the top, you can do the same thing directly in Sublime by selecting all of links in a single selection and choosing `Permute Lines: Unique` from the command palette (also available in the menu under `Edit > Permute Lines > Unique`. This command is available across all platforms with no external tools required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very trivial using `awk`:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
```

which basically means:

```
awk "!($0 in seen) {seen[$0];print}"
```

So if the line is not in the array it will add to it and print it. All subsequent lines if they exist in the array will be skipped.

```
$ cat file
> http://example.com/some/a-test-link.html
> http://example.com/some/a-test-link.html
> http://example.com/some/another-link.html
> http://example.com/some/another-link.html
> http://example.com/some/again-link.html
> http://example.com/some/again-link.html
$ awk '!seen[$0]++' file
> http://example.com/some/a-test-link.html
> http://example.com/some/another-link.html
> http://example.com/some/again-link.html
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sort -u file
> http://example.com/some/again-link.html
> http://example.com/some/another-link.html
> http://example.com/some/a-test-link.html
```

Comment: I did run this on a large file and `sort` used 3 seconds and `awk` 15 seconds.  So if speed is important use `sort` +1

Comment: It might matter whether the original file is already sorted or not. `awk` probably runs in constant time and `sort` is probably faster if the input is [partially] sorted. Of course if the input is guaranteed to be fully sorted, then you'd just use `uniq`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'G;/(http[^\n]*)\n.*\1/d;s/\n.*//;H' file
```

Use the hold space to hold previously seen URL's and delete lines which contain duplicates.

Comment: I have a file that contains 50 links. When I have used your sed command to filter my file links , i got only 3 links filtered , only first 6 links. It has ignored other 46 links of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a combination of sort and uniq:

```
sort input.txt | uniq
```

Sorting groups the duplicate links and uniq deletes all consecutive repeated links.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for you, but, if the links are in the order you've posted,  the following regex will give you just unique results.

```
/(http:\/\/.*?)\s+(?:\1)/gm
```

http://regex101.com/r/zB0pW3

Comment: I see these sort of posts regularly. What tool do you use to process the input file and create an output file with your regex? Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Tuga, Thanks for your comment. I just checked in regex1o1 and it working there with PCRE(PHP)  but somehow i can't make it work with egrep or sublimetext regex matching.

Comment: @TamimIbrahim I think you should stick with JS answer.